# Unable to run instrumented tests in Android dynamic feature module?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have added a dynamic feature module and have tried adding Instrumented tests there. However the configuration says "This current project cannot be run" when i try to run the test. I can run Instrumented tests in the main module however.